# Mvc Contrib Portable areas - swap out the bus?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib, servicebus, portable-areas

Is it possible to swap out the bus with something like masstransit? I've already got a service bus in my app so don't really want to introduce another one.

Ideally I'd be able to config it via the IoC but it sounds like the bus holds the IoC container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can provide your own implementation of `IApplicationBus`

```
public interface IApplicationBus:IList<Type>
{
    void Send(IEventMessage eventMessage);
    void SetMessageHandlerFactory(IMessageHandlerFactory factory);
}
```

Portable areas use the instance of `Bus` class that uses intrnally the provided instance for `IApplicationBus` interface or the local default of `ApplicationBus` class. It the following interface fits your need so you can easily do it.